# How to change the name of a contact in Android

Tags: android, contacts

I want to change the name of a contact in android without interaction of the user (like showing another action)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update (modify) contacts in Android by using a `ContentResolver` on the contact `ContentProvider`

Some links for you:

http://www.devdaily.com/java/jwarehouse/apps-for-android/SampleSyncAdapter/src/com/example/android/samplesync/platform/ContactManager.java.shtml

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html